# How to start windows service from application

Tags: winapi, windows-services, startup, access-rights

I have a `Windows Service` and i want to start it using `ServiceController`.The service runs as `LocalSystem`.When i am trying to `Start` it i get:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot open [service] service on
>   computer '.'.' 
> Inner Exception Win32Exception:Access is denied

**Main**

```
   static void Main(string[] args) {
            using (ServiceController controller = new ServiceController("someService")) {
                controller.Start();
            }
        }
```

Can i somehow elevate the rights programatically in order to start the service (even if i need to use `P/Invoke` for `Winapi` ? ) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do indeed need to elevate. That requires creating a new process to start the service, either explicitly with the `runas` shell verb, or using the COM elevation moniker.

Comment: Do i need to use `P\Invoke ` in order to do that ? Could you please provide some details on how to achieve that?